# Django: how can i change models variable value through template

Tags: python, django

I want to add function to change is_shown value when the button is pressed. It should be in view but I don't know where exactly.

**MODEL**

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    is_shown = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**VIEW**

```
class CouponListView(ListView):
    model = Coupon
    paginate_by = 10



def change_is_shown(request):
     c = Coupon.objects.first()
     c.is_shown = True
     c.save()
```

**URLS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name='coupons_list'),
    path('show_coupon', change_is_shown)
]
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<ul>
    {% for coupon in object_list %}
        {% if not coupon.is_used %}
            <li>
                {% if coupon.is_shown %}
                    {{ coupon.name }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ coupon.price }}
                    <input type="submit" value="show" name="show_coupon">
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Create another view to change the is_view status and send a request to it on clicking the button.

Comment: You should not do this in a template, *business logic* should be put in the *view*, not the *template*.

Comment: @Sumithran I 've change the code but it doesn't print anything. I don't know where and how i should place function.

Comment: Update the post with that fn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `href` the button to a different view. Then depending on which view receives the request, you can change the model object.

if you do your linking as follows -

```html
<a href="{% url 'changevalue' %}"> Submit </a>
```

or you can create a form that has a different redirect action if you want to use input.

Then in the corresponding input you can do the following -

```py
def change(request) :
  coupon = get_object_or_404( ".." = ".." )
  coupon.is_shown = True
  
  ................
  # your code
```